# syntax: multiple generic constraints and inheritance, interfaces

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, interface, type-bounds

what is the correct syntax for specifying multiple generic bounds/constraints in Kotlin?

```
class CustomClass<T> where T: Constraint1, T: Constraint2,
    ParentClass<T>(), Interface1 { /* ... */ }
```

here `Constraint1` and `Constraint2` are unrelated constraints/bounds on `T` (eg: disjoint interfaces that `T` implements) and `ParentClass` is a generic (base) class also. `Interface1` is an interface `CustomClass` will satisfy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the base class and the interfaces before the `where` clause:

```
class CustomClass<T>
    : ParentClass<T>(), Interface1
        where T : Constraint1, T : Constraint2 {
    /* ... */
}
```